# TabController+Riverpod+SharedPreferences occurs an error and warning in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create a tab application.

I got 2 problems at the moment. However, the application I developed seems to work at least for the time being, although errors do occur.

1. I get an error `Controller's length property (0) does not match the number of children (3) present in TabBarView's children property.`  every time I start the app. The reason is that I understand that TabController must be initialized during `initState()`, but `state = ref.watch...` can only be initialized after `build`, and that is why it happens, but I do not know how to improve the situation.
2. Since state is always updated with a delay, using `state.length` for length below would result in `Controller's length property (1) does not match the number of children (4) present in TabBarView'. s children property.`. Therefore, I use `notifier.state.length`, but I get a warning `The member 'state' can only be used within instance members of subclasses of 'package:state_notifier/state_notifier.dart`, but I don't know how to improve it.

```
      _tabController =
          TabController(vsync: this, length: notifier.state.length);
      setState(() {
        _tabController.animateTo(notifier.state.length - 1);
```

Here is a sample code to reproduce the problems above, since my app is more complicated.

main.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

import 'package:ex_tabcontroller/tab_item.dart';
import 'dart:developer' as developer;

late final SharedPreferences _prefs;

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  //await SharedPreferencesInstance.initialize();
  runApp(const ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends ConsumerState<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'MyApp',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePage();
}

class _MyHomePage extends ConsumerState<MyHomePage>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController _tabController;
  late List<TabItem> state;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: 0);

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      setState(() {
        _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: state.length);
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    state = ref.watch(itemListProvider);

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background,
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: () {
            addButtonTapped();
          },
        ),
        title: const Text('My App'),
        bottom: TabBar(
          indicatorColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimary,
          controller: _tabController,
          isScrollable: true,
          tabs: state.map((TabItem tab) {
            return Tab(
              child: Text(tab.title,
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleMedium),
              //text: tab.title,
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: _tabController,
        children: state.isEmpty
            ? <Widget>[]
            : state.map((item) {
                return TabPage(tab: item);
              }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }

  addButtonTapped() async {
    final notifier = ref.read(itemListProvider.notifier);
    final bool result =
        await notifier.add(title: (state.length + 1).toString());
    if (result) {
      _tabController =
          TabController(vsync: this, length: notifier.state.length);
      setState(() {
        _tabController.animateTo(notifier.state.length - 1);
      });
    }
  }
}

class TabPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TabPage({super.key, required this.tab});
  final TabItem tab;

  @override
  State<TabPage> createState() => _TabPageState();
}

class _TabPageState extends State<TabPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(child: Text(widget.tab.title));
  }
}

class ItemListNotifier extends StateNotifier<List<TabItem>> {
  static const String keyName = 'item';

  ItemListNotifier() : super([]) {
    initialized();
  }

  Future initialized() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final loaded = prefs.getStringList(keyName);
    if (loaded == null) {
      state = [
        const TabItem(
          title: '1',
        )
      ];
    } else {
      state = loaded.map((f) => TabItem.fromJson(json.decode(f))).toList();
    }
  }

  Future<bool> add({required String title}) async {
    final TabItem item = TabItem(
      title: title,
    );
    final items = [...state, item];

    final result = await _saveItemList(items);
    if (result == true) {
      state = items;
    }
    return result;
  }

  Future<void> update(List<TabItem> items) async {
    await _saveItemList(items).then((value) {
      if (value == true) {
        state = items;
      }
    });
  }

  Future<bool> _saveItemList(List<TabItem> items) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    List<String> itemStrings =
        items.map((f) => json.encode(f.toJson())).toList();

    return Future.value(prefs.setStringList(keyName, itemStrings));
  }
}

final itemListProvider = StateNotifierProvider<ItemListNotifier, List<TabItem>>(
  (ref) => ItemListNotifier(),
);
```

tan_item.dart

```
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';

part 'tab_item.freezed.dart';
part 'tab_item.g.dart';

@freezed
class TabItem with _$TabItem {
  const factory TabItem({
    required String title,
  }) = _TabItem;

  factory TabItem.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$TabItemFromJson(json);
}
```